# MySQL Table - Display name once along with their total score

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the below data entered into a database from a website:

```
 USER  |  SCORE
 abc   |    4
 ghi   |    2
 abc   |    6
 def   |    1
 abc   |    3
```

I want to now display a list of all the users, in alphabetical order, without repeating itself, and their total score. So with the table above, it would look something like:

```
 abc: 13
 def: 1
 ghi: 2
```

How do I do that? I would use php, right? Or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

User the Query to fetch data from database

```
SELECT USER, 
SUM (SCORE) as SCORE
FROM table
GROUP BY USER  ORDER BY USER ASC;
```

You should use PHP to fetch data from DB and print.

Comment: Accept as Answer if your query were resolved by my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be something like:

```
select user, sum(score) as total_score from table group by user order by user asc;
```

It can be done in MySQL without involving any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick using `MySql` query:

```
SELECT USER , SUM(SCORE) FROM table GROUP BY USER ORDER BY USER ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in database itself using the below SQL query.

```
SELECT SUM( SCORE ) , USER
FROM  SampleTable 
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY USER
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT User, SUM(Score) as Total_Score
FROM TableName
GROUP BY User
ORDER BY User;
```

No need to use javascript or php to achieve it. SQL is powerful enough to achieve it alone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch data from table and iterate through it. Below is SQL:

```
   SELECT User, SUM(Score) as total
   FROM TABLE_NAME
   GROUP BY User
   ORDER BY User;
```